# Amount is not changing to dollars on the paypal page when I place an order

Tags: magento-1.7

My base currency is set to INR not USD. I am using only 2 currencies INR and USD on my site. When I want to checkout through paypal the INR amount is not converted to USD, although the $ currency symbol is seen on the paypal page but the amount is not converted to dollars
Like (if base price is Rs 5,600 it shows USD 5,600 instead of USD 100 in paypal. Basically its not converting the base currency)

Can anyone of this great community help me out of this.

Thanks & regards.
Avanish

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue. If you happen to find the solution, please let me know..